# Office 365 Message header X-MS-Exchange-Organization-Recipient-P2-Type: Bcc missing

Tags: office365

As part of a workflow I want to move the email with "To" and "BCC" set to same mail address to a specific folder. I was using an inbox rule with condition :   “Message Header Includes : X-MS-Exchange-Organization-Recipient-P2-Type: Bcc”, . This was working okay until we migrated to Office 365 but stopped working now.

After upgrade to Office 365, the message header "X-MS-Exchange-Organization-Recipient-P2-Type: Bcc" seems to be missing when both To and BCC are same.

Anyone faced similar issue or any idea how to resolve this?

Thank you for your help.